# how to write behaviour tests for Struts 2?

Tags: java, struts2, cucumber-jvm

I am writing behaviour tests with cucumber-jvm for a legacy project using Struts 2.

I have successfully used `cucumber-jvm` to test the behaviour of a feature of the application. But I think I have chosen the wrong starting point: I am currently creating the action and calling its methods directly, as such:

**users.feature**

```
Given that I am in the Users Page (I create a UserAction object in my Step Definition)
When I press "list" (I call the userAction.list() method)
Then I should see the following users: // list of users
```

The problem is, my step definition would become increasingly complex as I am testing more and more features that have a "list" method, as I'd have to identify which Action's method I need to call.

The solution would be to invoke the actions dynamically, as jsp pages do. How do I do that from Java? I'm new to the Struts 2 World, and so far I have found some DispatchAction tutorials with jsp pages.

I already have an ActionContext, Request and Session, as such:

```
// Mock a session
session = Mockito.mock(HttpSession.class);

// mock a request
request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
Mockito.when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(session);

// create a context
Map<String, Object> contextMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
contextMap.put(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST, request);
ActionContext.setContext(new ActionContext(contextMap));
ActionContext.getContext().getActionInvocation();
```

Comment: There's no DispatchAction in Struts 2. I'm not class on what the issue is, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton all actions on Struts2 provide this functionality. The issue I'm facing is how can I call my action dynamically, as one would do from a jsp page. Are you class now?